# Unexpected value for 'this' in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn the 'this' concept in Javascript.
I have this simple code snippet:

```
sayHi = function(){
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(this);
}

class Test{
    constructor(){
        console.log(this);
    }
    instanceFunction(){
        sayHi();
    }
}

let ob = new Test();
ob.instanceFunction();
```

Output is:

```
Test {}
hi
[Global Object in Node]
```

May be I'm missing something basic, but I was expecting the third line in the output to be `Test {}` instead of `[Global Object in Node]`. How come the third line is the Global object, when invoked with an instance of `Test` class ?

Comment: Because `this` inside a function refers by default to `window` or the global object...? It doesn't matter *when or where it is invoked*, but *how it is invoked*, whether attached to an object or instance.

Comment: maybe change `sayHi()` to `sayHi.call(this)`

Comment: [`this` in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). *"when invoked with an instance of Test class ?"* - It isn't invoked *with* an instance of `Test`, it is invoked *from* an instance of `Test`. Not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn. I get it now.